# Determine the input impedances of a circuit

Tags: bjt, ltspice, input-impedance

I'm studying a circuit with BJT's and I'm asked to determine the input resistances of the two amplification steps of the circuit. The circuit I'm analyzing is the following one:

[image]

To determine the input resistances I performed an AC analysis and obtained the following results:

[image]

I know that the values are not perceptible but they are Rin1=23.272231 kohm and Rin2=220.77106 kohm. 
I decided to choose a somewhat random value in the zone of the graphic where the curves are constant (I'm not sure if this is correct...).

Well this value are very different from what I obtained when I analyze the theoretical values of the input resistances.

Using:

$$R_{i2}=(β+1) R_{E3}//R_L+r_{π2}$$

where r_{π2} is 9.375 kohm and beta is 300. 
I obtained R_i2=240.375 kΩ

And for Ri1

$$R_{i1}=R_1//R_2//(r_π1+R_{E1} (1+β))$$
I obtained R_i1=20.183kohm.

I used the small-signal analysis models to determine this...

Now this is odd. I'm getting an error of about 15% on Ri1 and 7% on Ri2. Am I doing something wrong or are this deviations perfectly normal and dependent on the methods used on the theoretical analysis and on LTSpice. Can someone help me clarify this?

Comment: Your uploaded picture needs re-saving and re-uploading. Have you used the transistors, separately, to determine their values? Models usually differ from real life. Also, you could try to use a current source at the input, and plot `1/V(vs)`, but I suspect it will be the same.

Comment: How do you determine the r_pi value?  Also, LTspice includes ro resistance and VT at 27 degrees,

Answer (score 1):

How does the SPICE model differ from hybrid-pi? Are those differences important?

Comment: Beta is slightly different (294.3 versus 300). Also the values of r_pi might be a little bit different, because the currents are slightly different than 0.8 mA. Will that be enough reason?

Answer (score 0):

At \$1 \textrm{kHz}\$ the \$C_E\$ capacitor reactance is around :

\$X_C \approx \frac{0.16}{F \cdot C}\approx 1.6\textrm{k}\Omega\$

So the \$Z_E\$ impedance will be around:

\$Z_E = R_{E1} + R_{E2}||X_{C_E} \approx 1.2 \textrm{k}\Omega \$

And input impedance is:

\$R_{in1} = R_1||R_2||(Z_E + r_e)(\beta+1) \approx 23.232 \textrm{k}\Omega\$

Rin1 = 1/( 1/68 + 1/39+1/((1.2+0.0325)*301))

I assume \$I_C = 0.8 \textrm{mA}\$ and \$r_e = \frac {26\textrm{mV}}{I_C} = 32.5\Omega\$

As for \$R_{in2}\$ is equal around:

\$ R_{in2} = (R_{E3}||R_L||r_o)(\beta+1)+r_{\pi2}\$

Because the LTspice includes \$r_o\$ (Early effect).

So to get almost exactly the same result you need to know \$ro\$ or Early voltage \$ \textrm{VAF}\$ in LTspice.